# Execute code inside IF statement in all cases but one

Tags: php, if-statement

What would be the right way to do this? For example:

```
if ($var1 == 'value1' && $var2 == 'value2') {
    //code2
    return;
} else {
    //code1
}
//code2
```

I was thinking of using keyword `continue` insided `if` but I would also like to know if there is a better way?

**EDIT**

To be more precise I am going to try explaining it better. `$var1` is current logged in user's role and `$var2` is role of user whose details (let's say email) are being inserted into table. `code2` is part that always need to be executed and there are a lot of lines there and therefore I shouldn't duplicate it. `code1` is part where I am informing user that he is supposed to verify his email address and I am inserting into table the same thing (that email is still not verified). There is only one case when this shouldn't happen and when email should be automatically verified upon adding and that case is when `$var1` is ADMIN and `$var2` is REGULAR USER. In all other cases, `code1` should be executed.

Comment: Don't understand your question please more elobrate

Comment: Exactly. It seems to me you do not need the else statement at all, because the code 2 should be executed all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question

```
if ($var1 == 'value1' && $var2 == 'value2') {
    //code2
    return;
} else {
    //code1
}
//code2
```

That sounds to me that `code2` should be executed no matter what. In that case, you have to switch the `if` statement:

```
if( $var1 != 'value1' || $var2 != 'value2'){
  code1();
}
code2();
```

The `code2` will be always execute and in the case you need, the `code1` will execute too